# Create multiple custom permissions

Tags: lightning, data-loader, workbench, create-records, custom-permission

I have a requirement to create multiple(around 100) custom permissions. Can this be done using data loader or workbench? In data loader when we select insert option I don't see custom permissions object. This object is available if we select export in data loader

Answer (score 0):

Custom Permissions are a type of metadata, so you need to use [CustomPermission](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_custompermission.htm) to create them. Probably the easiest way to do this would be a NodeJS/Python/etc script to output all of the files you need, then use Salesforce DX to deploy (though you could also use workbench at this point).

Comment: I have list of custom permissions to be created in a CSV file. Is there a way we can create these custom permissions via data loader or workbench instead of creating them manually. Thanks.

Comment: @SudhirBalijepalli No, but you can use a simple node script or something.